# Set default Bluetooth service for a device ("Listen to Music" vs. "VoIP")

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, services

I have a Bluetooth headset that pairs and connects fine. But every time I restart the computer and turn on the headset, it defaults to "Forward VoIP Calls to Handsfree", which has a very poor low-bandwidth audio delivery. I must manually open up the device Services, disconnect from the VoIP service and connect to "Listen to Music".

It's a minor annoyance, but one of those day-to-day things that you wish you could just figure out. Hence this question.

Answer (score -2):

Tom and anyone that finds this, I had the same problem, every time you rebooted it would reset it to on. I saw a link on the web that said once you un-check the "Forward VOP calls to handsfree" you need to reboot immediately. This fixed it for me it now keeps the setting unchecked!!Yeah!!